# Plotting Residuals vs Predicted Values

Tags: modeling, least-squares, residuals, validation

In textbooks, residual plots are described as have predicted (fitted) values on the  x-axis, with the y-axis being the difference between the predicted and observed values. However, I'm having trouble understanding why this is. It seems to me that a more useful residual plot would have the observed values on the x-axis.

For example:

```
# integers 1 through 500
y = np.linspace(1, 500, 500)
# 500 random samples
X = np.random.randn(500)

# build an OLS model
X = sm.add_constant(X)
model = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()

plt.scatter(y, model.fittedvalues, alpha=0.2)
plt.xlabel('Observed')
plt.ylabel('Predicted')
plt.title('Observed vs Predicted')
plt.show()

plt.scatter(y, y-model.fittedvalues, alpha=0.2)
plt.xlabel('Observed')
plt.ylabel('Residual')
plt.title('Residuals vs Observed')
plt.show()

plt.scatter(model.fittedvalues, y-model.fittedvalues, alpha=0.2)
plt.xlabel('Predicted')
plt.ylabel('Residual')
plt.title('Residuals vs Predicted')
plt.show()
```

Yields these plots:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Obviously, this model is a bad fit - the predictor is random. However, the plot of the residuals vs fitted values looks fine. If I were to look at the plot of residuals vs observed, the straightline would be a clear indicator that my model is poor - there is some unexplained variation that my model is not capturing.

Why are residual plots made against predictors instead of against observed values?

The context is that I have a model that I believe fits quite poorly, and I see results like these example graphs. I would like to include the residuals vs observed as evidence that the model is poor, but this does not seem to be common practice. Advice on how to use a residual plot when explaining model fit is very welcome.

Comment: *Pace* all the bad textbooks and blogs that assert otherwise, goodness of a model is not measured by "unexplained variation."  These plots are used to assess deviations behind the underlying probability assumptions and the data.  Your interpretation of them is exactly the opposite of what it should be, though.

Comment: Can you provide a more useful suggestion on how to interpret these plots?

Comment: I don't need to, because a great deal has already been posted on this site about such questions: please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+residual+plot+diagnostic for some of this material, then modify the search according to your interests.

Comment: You also don't need to post unhelpful comments in the first place. I am aware that I don't understand - that is exactly why I am asking a question about it after trying to figure it out for myself by reading and searching through other questions. Creating a negative environment for people who are trying to earnestly learn and correct their misinterpretations does a disservice to the entire CV community.